# Sorting and removing non-duplicate rows in google sheet and keeping non-duplicate rows and duplicate rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am fairly new to Google sheets, and essentially what I am trying to do is remove all non-duplicate values that do not exist or is listed in another sheet or row - and also store the non-duplicate values somewhere else

In my example [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V0T8doTMQiLrLE9LKPpRy467cIhRTiDcvzn6te5BGvg/edit?usp=sharing), I am trying to only keep the Alcohol names that are listed in column G

So in my case, I only want to keep the following records:

```
Alcohol Name    Alcohol Type    Origin
Martell Cognac  France
Captain Morgans Rum Jamaica
Wray & Nephew   Rum Jamaica
Hennessey   Cognac  France
Barcardi    Rum Cuba
Courvoiser  Cognac  France
Famous Grouse   Scotch  Scotland
Jack Daniels    Whisky  USA
Grants  Scotch  Scotland
Ciroc   Vodka   France
```

I also want to keep any that did not appear in the list in a separate table like this:

```
Alcohol Name    Alcohol Type    Origin
Russian Standard    Vodka   Russia
Southern Comfort    Bourbon USA
Ciroc   Whisky  France
```

At the moment I am having to manually check a longer list one by one and it is taking lot of time and my arm hurts..

If someone can please help me with sorting it such that it looks like this, would be great! I don't know if there are formulas we can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula to only keep the Alcohol names that are listed in column G

```
=QUERY(A1:C," where A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,G2:G)&"' ",1)
```

To order them use

```
=QUERY(A1:C," where A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,G2:G)&"' order by A",1)
```

[image]

Use this to keep any that did not appear in the list in a separate table.
You see, you only put `not` in the formula

```
=QUERY(A1:C," where not A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,G2:G)&"' ",1)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I accepted your answer now. The only bit I still dont quite understand is what does the `|` pipeline do in the `'"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,G2:G)&"'`?

Comment: The pipeline `|` is like `OR` in regex. Read [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Where) about `QUERY`

Comment: Thanks mate. Just trying to understand how and where the pipeline `|` is being used in this context. I get the `1` means true for empty rows.

Comment: To understand where the pipeline `|` is being used in this context, try this alone: `=TEXTJOIN("|",1,G2:G)`